# nth-child conflicts with last-of-type?

Tags: html, css

With this snippet

```css
.post { border-bottom: 1px solid black; }
.post:nth-child(2n) { background-color: #DDD; }
.post:last-of-type { border-bottom: none; }
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="post">This is post 1.</div>
  <div class="post">This is post 2.</div>
  <div class="post">This is post 3.</div>
  <div id="last">This is not a post! This is the last element here.</div>
</div>
```

I want to remove the border between post 3 and the last element.

Comment: But your last-of-type div shows with id not a class as per your screenshot..

Comment: Indeed...it appears that you are after "last of class"...which does not exist,

Comment: For last-of-type to work you have to let it know what type in this case a div so div.class:last....etc

Comment: I'm not looking for the ID-d part. I'm looking for the last-before line. But one sec.. I'll just build up an example quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally came to the solution:

```css
.post { border-bottom: 1px solid black; }
.post:nth-child(2n) { background-color: #DDD; }
.post:nth-last-child(2) { border-bottom: none; }
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="post">This is post 1.</div>
  <div class="post">This is post 2.</div>
  <div class="post">This is post 3.</div>
  <div id="last">This is not a post! This is the last element here.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice fix! Was trying the jquery route but thats def the way to do it!

Comment: Thanks :) But... the thing is I can't really use jQuery :DD

Comment: @HisPowerLevelIsOver9000 And I was also at changing my generator script which made this HTML. :D

Answer (score 0):

As there is no `last-of-class` you will have to fall back to either Javascript of switching the border to top on all the classed divs and removing it from the first one.

```css
div div {
  height:50px;
  background: pink;
  }

.post {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}
.post:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: #DDD;
}
.post:first-child {
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="post">This is post 1.</div>
  <div class="post">This is post 2.</div>
  <div class="post">This is post 3.</div>
  <div id="last">This is not a post! This is the last element here.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I've already made it possible with the bottom border. See my answer up there.